# Django refrence non field value at database level

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

```py
class Author(models.Model):
    ...


class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    book_seq = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('author', 'book_seq')

    def create_book_for_author(cls, author):
        book_seq = Book.objects.filter(author=author).count() + 1
        Book.objects.create(author=author, book_seq=book_seq)
```

Is there any way to reference this `book_seq = Book.objects.filter(author=author).count() + 1` at database level because if this line concurrently then the unique constraint will fail and the second one to reach the database with insert query will fail. I know one option is transaction but is there any other way? `F()` object only works with concrete field not with database query.